# SQL group by every 2 rows

Tags: sql, oracle

What we have:

```
id|value1|value2|
1 |15    |null  |
2 |null  |12    |
3 |98    |null  |
4 |null  |41    |
```

What we want - group data every two lines to have this result:

```
idGrouped|value1|value2|
1        |15    |12    |
2        |98    |41    |
```

I think I could use modulo on the id column.

It's an Oracle database (but I would prefer to do it in 'pure sql')

*Edit*

IT's maybe not clear, but the important part is the 'idGrouped' column. I simplified the example, but I need to group to data every 2 rows (or 'n' rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select floor( (id - 1) / 2) as id, max(value1), max(value2)
from t
group by floor( (id - 1) / 2);
```

This assumes that `id` is incrementing with no gaps.  If this is not true, use `row_number()`:

```
select floor( (seqnum - 1) / 2) as id, max(value1), max(value2)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor( (seqnum - 1) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select value1, value2
from table1
where value1 is not null or value2 is not null
```